# Updating AWS Elasticsearch cluster settings

Tags: aws-elasticsearch

By default in Elasticsearch, the maximum number of open scrolls is 500 but I need to increase this number. There s no problem in updating "search.max_open_scroll_context" in local machine but AWS Elasticsearch has not allowed to make changes.

While trying to update with answer given in this thread [configure-search-max-open-scroll-context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55989369/how-to-configure-search-max-open-scroll-context-in-elasticsearch), the response is: `{"Message":"Your request: '/_cluster/settings' payload is not allowed."}` while I can perform such operation in my local Elasticsearch but AWS Elasticsearch doesn't seems to allow such operation. Does anyone has answer to this for AWS Elasticsearch or have faced similar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is restricted in AWS ES for customer end.

You need to reach out to AWS Support Team for this. Just let them know the value of "search.max_open_scroll_context" that you are looking for and they will update it from the backend.

Comment: Seems like that is the only way. Did the same, Thank you

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticsearch-service/latest/developerguide/aes-supported-es-operations.html#es_version_7_10) the link to AWS-supported operations on elasticsearch.

Currently, AWS doesn't support updating "search.max_open_scroll_context" as of now. You can definitely contact AWS support to increase the scroll context count. Alternatively, you can use Search-After API instead of scroll.